# VECM when only one variable is cointegrated

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

What does it imply for my VECM model if only one variable is cointegrated?

```
out = coint_johansen(endog=df[[var_1,var_2,var_3]],
det_order = 0,
k_ar_diff =2)
d = {'0.90':0, '0.95':1, '0.99':2}
traces = out.lr1
cvts = out.cvt[:, d['0.95']]
def adjust(val, length= 6): return str(val).ljust(length)
print('Name   ::  Test Stat > C(95%)    =>   Signif  \n', '--'*20)
for col, trace, cvt in zip(df[[var_1,var_2,var_3]].columns, traces, cvts):
    print(adjust(col), ':: ', adjust(round(trace,2), 9), ">", adjust(cvt, 8), ' =>  ' , trace > cvt)
```

The output is

```
>>> Name   ::  Test Stat > C(95%)    =>   Signif  
 ----------------------------------------
var_1::  32.31     > 29.7961   =>   True
var_2::  7.57      > 15.4943   =>   False
var_3::  2.06      > 3.8415    =>   False
```

What is the implication to the model if only one variable shows cointegration?

Comment: The output you've constructed is nonsensical: the trace statistic applies to the number of cointegrating relationships, not to each variable. Likewise, "only one variable shows cointegration" doesn't mean anything, variables are cointegrated with each other.

Comment: Your response led me down the right path: the summary output is interpreted as, 'there is one cointegration vector' which is also then the rank of my VECM model.